# Existing Silverlight project can't get compiled in the Windows 7

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have Silverlight 4 RIA Project targeting .net 4 framework. the project get compiled on Windows XP no problem. Once we try to compile it under Windows 7 it starts complaining about issues related to the RIA Service. For example, client generated code for the following class will miss the MyArray property.

```
class Custom
{
   public int A {get;set;}

   public UnitItem[] MyArray {get;set;}
}
```

where UnitItem defined as

```
public partial class UnitItem
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }
    public UnitItem[] Subitems { get; set; }
}
```

has someone came across this issue before?
Thanks

Comment: When you say that it 'starts complaining', what do you mean?  Do you get one or more error messages, and if so, what?  What is the definition of the type `Unit`?  What version of WCF RIA Services do you have installed on your Windows XP and Windows 7 machines?

Comment: most of the errors related to KeyAttribute is not defined for particular class, or the compiler can not find specific variable on the client side, because it doesn't get generated by the RIA Code generator. 
RIA Service v 1.0

Comment: I seem to remember some issues with WCF RIA Services V1.0 that were fixed when I installed WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1. These issues related to 'complex objects', which, if I remember correctly, are objects that contain other objects.  Could you try installing SP1 (or maybe even SP2)?

Comment: I've tried installing WCF RIA SP1/SP2 it didn't help

Comment: Is this for all WCF RIA Services projects on the Windows 7 machine, or just one?  Does this affect one Windows 7 machine or more than one?  Also, you're still being somewhat coy with the details of your problem: **exactly what** are the error messages you're seeing?  Would it be possible perhaps to put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the client generated code under xp INCLUDE the SubItems property ? I'll be amazed if it does, I think you need to use the AssociationAttribute